# Laravel Form Building Not Passing Array Of Items

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I passed my tags and on my form I have a multi-select. Although when I do `tags[]` nothing gets passed in. If I do just `tag` then only one of them submits.

```
public function create()
    {
        $categories = Category::pluck('name', 'id');
        $tags = Tag::pluck('name', 'id');
        return view('posts.create')->withCategories($categories)->withTags($tags);
        }

  {{ Form::label('tags', "Select Tag")}}
   {{ Form::select('tags[]', $tags, null, ['class' => 'selectpicker', 'multiple', 'data-live-search="true"', 'data-actions-box="true"', 'data-width="100%', 'show-menu-arrow']) }}
```

Comment: {"1":"sexiness","2":"rockets","3":"marketing","4":"PHP"} ---- Just the array isn't getting passed once selected when I put in [], else It just submits one.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a glitch in the current version Laravel / Form Builder. If you do the old fashion select way it works as it should.

```
public function create()
    {
        $categories = Category::pluck('name', 'id');
        $tags = Tag::all();
        return view('posts.create')->withCategories($categories)->withTags($tags);
    }

<select name="tags[]" class="selectpicker show-tick" multiple data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" show-menu-arrow>
   @foreach ($tags as $tag)
     <option value="{{$tag->id}}">{{$tag->name}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```